# Connecting TFT Display MI0283QT-9A to ESP32

Tags: esp32, tft

I have purchased a MI0283QT-9A TFT display (https://download.mikroe.com/documents/add-on-boards/other/display/tft-proto/tft-proto-manual-v200.pdf) which is
driven by the ILI9341 display controller.

I've managed to find the following board specification: http://pub.ucpros.com/download/tft_320_240_mi0283qt_9a_v1_3_spec.pdf

First of all, the pins are named differently from all the examples I can find for connecting it to my ESP32 microcontroller. For example, the TFT specs describe:

```
33 SDO Serial Output Signal
34 SDI Serial Input Signal
35 RD Read execution control pin
36 WRX(D/CX) Write execution control pin ; Serial Register select s Signal
37 D/CX(SCL) Register select signal; Serial Interface Clock
38 CSX Chip Select Signal
39 TE Tearing effect out pin synchronize MPU to frame writng
```

But this Adafruit ILI9341 example (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ILI9341/blob/master/examples/graphicstest/graphicstest.ino) talks about CS, DC, MOSI, CLK, RST, and MISO.

I think these map as follows, **can anyone confirm that**?

```
ESP32 = TFT
--------------
DC    = RS
CLK   = WR, although maybe it should connect to DC???
CS    = CSX
MOSI  = SDI
RST   = RST
MISO  = SDO
```

I'm really unsure about the first two!

Second, in the PDF it refers to note 1 on page 11:

[image]

So as far as I can tell, I need to set the voltage high/low on the four IM* pins, depending upon the interface I want to use. So the second question is **which interface does the Adafruit ILI9341 library use**?

Comment: The wiring depends on what mode you are using the board in - which mode you select from the table of modes you show (what settings you give to IM0-IM3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a 4-wire 8-bit serial SPI compatible interface.  To get that you have to set the IMx pins to the right state to enable that interface.  That means:

- IM0 = LOW
- IM1 = HIGH
- IM2 = HIGH
- IM3 = HIGH

You can hard-wire those to GND for LOW and +3.3V for HIGH.

That will then configure it to work in the right mode for you, where it gives you access to the following pins:

```
| Display  | ESP32   | Function                    |
|----------|---------|-----------------------------|
| SCL (RS) | SCK     | Serial clock                |
| SDI      | MOSI    | Serial data Master -> Slave |
| SDO      | MISO    | Serial data Slave -> Master |
| D/CX (WR)| DC      | Data / Command register sel |
| CSX      | CS      | Chip Select (Active Low)    |
| RST      | RST     | Reset                       |
```

Comment: what does "active low" mean, next to CS?

Comment: is the RST pin on the ESP32, the EN pin, or some pin of my choice?

Comment: It means that the input is considered "activated" when it receives a LOW signal. I.e., the chip is activated when you apply LOW to that pin.

Comment: RST and DC are pins of your choice. They are just GPIOs to control the screen.

Comment: thanks for the help. I still have a problem with SCL and DCX: according to the specs: TFT Pin36: WRX//D/CX) Write execution control pin ; Serial Register select s Signal; TFT Pin37: D/CX(SCL)  Register select signal; Serial Interface Clock.   none of those names are on TFT board. but we do have RS = Register Select => so DC is the RS pin. that means SCL/SCK must be the WR pin. ok, ill check that.

Comment: forget the above comment.  Thanks for the help. I still have a problem with SCL and DCX: according to the specs: TFT Pin36: WRX//D/CX) Write execution control pin ; Serial Register select s Signal; TFT Pin37: D/CX(SCL)  Register select signal; Serial Interface Clock.   There is no pin on the board with the name D/CX(SCL), but there is one called RS and one called WR. So I guess WR is the DC and RS is the clock?

Comment: Map the pins using the schematic.  Pin 36 is DC in serial mode. That's LCD-WR# on the board (WR). Pin 37 is SCL in serial mode. 37 is RS on the board. So DC -> WR and SCK -> RS. The board is really labelled from a 16-bit 8080 interface perspective.

Comment: OK, I started using the SPI pins of the ESP32 rather than GPIO pins. DC/WR=12; SCK/RS=18; CS=15; SDI/MOSI=23; RST=14; MISO/SDO=19. the board now flickers, although it doesnt show what it supposed to. and the program now outputs non-zero values: Display Power Mode: 0xFF; MADCTL Mode: 0xE0; Pixel Format: 0xFF; Image Format: 0xFF; Self Diagnostic: 0xFF. see also https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/esp32_pinmap.png

Comment: The IM0 pin was unplugged from gnd => stuck it back in, and now it works perfectly. thanks!!!

Comment: Excellent.  There's not much I haven't learned about TFTs over the years ;)

Answer (score 1):

Same (TFT proto board) tested Arduono DUE.

Pins IM1-3 HI, IM0 LO. (4-wire 8-bit data serial interface)

SDI - MOSI, SDO - MISO,RS - CLK, RD - HI, WR - D9, CS - D10, Reset - Reset (D8)

Driver UTFT myGLCD (ILI9341_S5P, MOSI, SCK, 10,8,9);

or

```
// For the Adafruit shield, these are the default.
#define TFT_DC 9
#define TFT_CS 10
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341 (TFT_CS, TFT_DC);
```

Backlight needs resistor!